# Eclipse tomcat startup failure

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm running  Eclipse Indigo (3.7) on Windows 7 (x64 bit) and when I start Tomcat 7.0.12 using   Mongrel ( an Eclipse plugin for running Tomcat in 
Eclipse) I get:

```
May 24, 2012 7:56:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
SEVERE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:425)
```

I have jdk1.7.0_04 on my computer.

Things I've tried:

-another version of Tomcat

-deleting and re-adding Tomcat  servers

-making sure system java and Eclipse java are both jdk1.7.0_04

-googling for possible solutions for 2 days now .

No luck with any of these. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit late; but for anyone else who may have this problem; it turned out i had put a backslash \ at the end on my CATALINA_HOME environment variable (I was using windows). When i removed it, i could start using catalina run command.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who came here seeking for help. I found this forum entry useful to solve my Tomcat startup problem: http://www.coderanch.com/t/458931/Tomcat/running-tomcat
Even though they're discussing Tomcat 5, it helped me to get my instance of Tomcat 7 running.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem and did solve it by renaming the folder to contain latin characters only.

Here are pictures of my case:

[Before Fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuyJi.png)  and [After Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7N0T.png)

My system details:

```
OS : Window 11 (x64 bit)
IDE : Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers - 2023-03
Java : 1.8
Tomcat : 7.0.65
```

and I tried this fix before ->
[Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029810/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-catalina-startup-bootstrap)