# Tomcat 8.0 64-bit server not starting and getting error from Catalina.bat

Tags: java, tomcat

I am unable to start Tomcat 8.0 64-bit server. I have catalina.bat run also. I am getting the below message.

```
01-Oct-2014 10:22:11.415 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.ini
tClassLoaders Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:146)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
```

Could you please advise?

Comment: Just an idea, but since this is windows... do you have any whitespaces in the path to tomcat?

Comment: This is my path: C:\Users\java_user\apache-tomcat-8.0.12-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8 in Windows 7.

Comment: are u sure tomcat is installed there??? if you downloaded the tomcat installer it extracts it in c/programfiles

Comment: I rebooted my machine and it got resolved. My tomcat server is up and running. I don't know what exactly happened.

Answer (score 9):

Had a similar issue with Tomcat 8 and Java 8 on Windows 8, and after little bit of playing around, I noticed that `CATALINA_HOME` was set as "`CATA_HOME=c:\mydir\tomcat.8.0\`"

I just changed it to `CATA_HOME=c:\mydir\tomcat.8.0`" and it fixed all the issues. I never thought ending back slash would cause the issue but there you are...it did!!!

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this problem by **deleting the server and creating a new one**. Much simpler than trying to diagnose what went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you didn't miss any quotation mark(s) around commas in catalina.properties. In my case it was: `...,"${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.base}/../lib/*.jar"` instead of `...,"${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar`**"`,`"**`${catalina.base}/../lib/*.jar"`.

Answer (score 2):

Faced similar issue.
Modified my CATALINA_HOME path as below:
Previous:
CATALINA_HOME=D:\Personal\Projects\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.37-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\

Changed to:
CATALINA_HOME=D:\Personal\Projects\Apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.37-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.37

VOILA!
It worked.

Comment: yes its about tomcat path.i update my tomcat path and its worked.thx

Answer (score 0):

Today I have faced the same issue. I have defined my sources files in catalina.properties near `server.loader=C:\aaconfigs\appconfigs,C:\aaconfigs\appParams.`
this caused the issue. When i changed it to following `server.loader=C:/aaconfigs/appconfigs,C:/aaconfigs/appParams.` error got resolved.

I hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same issue and just deleted the server from my workspace and added a new one, didnt get the error again. Its working fine for now.