# Tomcat installation issue - "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: tomcat

I want to create a 'Dynamic web project' in eclipse. To do so, I want Tomcat to be listed in 'Target runtime' combo. So, I'm trying to install Tomcat. I changed the mode of all .sh files in TOMCAT_HOME/bin as follows;

1. [root@localhost opt]# cd apache-tomcat-7.0.12/bin/
2. [root@localhost bin]# chmod 0755 *.sh

I could see that there is a problem with my installation.
 How to resolve the below errors and install tomcat successfully?

On executing **./version.sh** command, I get the following

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```

On executing **./configtest.sh**, I get the following error;

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_91
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
Configuration error detected!
```

Comment: Hope you will find your answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029810/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-catalina-startup-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Look at this evidence you gave us on the question:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/admin/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M6-src
```

The "-src" means that you have downloaded the source code which requires to be built.

Download the "bin distribution", for example the first file on the "Core" section in this link https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi

Now it will run.
Anyway, refer to the RUNNING.txt file on the main installation folder and you will be fine.